# How do I set the firstresponder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a view built through IB, there's a text view and and button on it. When the view shows up I would like to have the keyboard to be already displayed.

I tried to set the first responder in the didViewLoad but that didn't work.

I do have an IBOutlet that is connected to the textView and related accessor.

Comment: Check out this link : http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/004-TextFieldApp.pl This most likely has your answers.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Looks like you may have accidentally misspelled the method name *didViewLoad* instead of *viewDidLoad*. All you should need there (assuming your IBOutlet is connected in IB) is the following:

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: That should be [textView.window makeFirstResponder:textView];

Comment: @voidref You'd be correct if the question was about Cocoa but it's not, it's about Cocoa touch. There's no `makeFirstResponder:` method in `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is tagged as cocoa-touch but this is highly ranked in Google and I ran into trouble with using [-becomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/becomeFirstResponder) on OS X; it did nothing. From the [NSResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html) documentation,

> Use the NSWindow `makeFirstResponder:` method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.

So on OS X use,

```
[[myView window] makeFirstResponder:myView];
```

Comment: If you are using IB, the `NSWindow` has a `initialFirstResponder` Outlet that allows you to connect a view that will be the first responder when the window is first drawn on screen.

Answer (score -1):

For Swift

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```