# Why doesn't a tap on UITextField open the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm very new to Objective-C and Cocoa Touch. I have been following tutorials from a book. Currently I have a `UITextField` that is supposed to open the keyboard on a tap from the user to enter input.

However, when I run the app, nothing happens when I tap on the text field. I've checked all its attributes and made sure that it's enabled and user interaction is enabled.

Is there something really obvious I'm missing? I've read the tutorial two to three times, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: How was the textfield created? By code or by XIB?

Comment: Having this same issue. Anyone with a fix?

Answer (score 0):

have you linked everything in interface builder (if you created the textfield by XIB)

Answer (score -1):

Set that textfield as firstresponder. See [How do I set the firstresponder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422733/how-do-i-set-the-firstresponder).

Comment: That should happen automatically when the text field is tapped.

Comment: Yeah, but I think I remember having a similar issue and that fixed it for me. Maybe I'm not recalling correctly.